# Overlap two centered elements using CSS flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to absolutely center two elements in the middle of the page, with one behind the other. The intent is to have a page that is fully responsive with a circle in the middle which has a pulse effect behind it.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fy8vD/2003/) of the below:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.sphere {
  display: flex;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.container:after {
  display: flex;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 300px;
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  animation: pulsate 2.5s ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0.0;
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  margin: auto;
}
@keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sphere"></div>
</div>
```

#### Method:

I'm currently using flexbox to center a container div with a circle inside, and an `:after` tag on the container to create the pulse. I've tried using z-indexing (doesn't seem to do anything), and absolute positioning (which requires hard-coded px values which I'd like to stay away from).

Is there a graceful way to achieve this using flexbox?

#### Desired Effect:

[This is close](http://jsfiddle.net/Fy8vD/2004/), but I'd like to move away from using px values for the `:after` element if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if that'll do it, but you could simply add to your :after

```
position: absolute;
top   : 0;
left  : 0;
bottom: 0;
right : 0;
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ccyd6xh1/

**Update** that was a quick draft, and was not absolutely responsive. If you want the effect the really follow your sphere and its size, you should add the `:after` on the sphere element and not its container, and use % width and height (here the glow grows to `130%` of the sphere size):

http://jsfiddle.net/tjoo739y/

Comment: woah, that's awesome - I didn't know you could center an absolute element by initialising all its directions to 0. Thanks for the help!

Comment: np, check my update if you want something more robust, otherwise the effect will work only when the sphere is in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

This is easily created with `position: absolute`, which removes the elements / pseudo elements from the normal flow of the document so they ignore each other. You *can* use flexible units and don't need to use `px`. There is no need for the flex properties to achieve this.

- The `.sphere` element is given its height / width and is centered. The circles conform to this width / height and position.
- Using a pseudo-element for the black circle is the easiest way to have it overlap the white pulsating circle. Both the circles are now siblings and the second sibling will overlap naturally
- The pseudo-element children of `.sphere` are stretched to fit the parents height and width with the `top` / `left` / `bottom` / `right` properties set at `0`.
- One way to keep this responsive is to use a [viewport width unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) for the width and height. This will keep the height / width 1:1.

#### Example

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}
.sphere {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  height: 10vw;
  width: 10vw;
}
.sphere:before,
.sphere:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.sphere:before {
  background: #FFF;
  animation: pulsate 2.5s ease-out infinite;
}
.sphere:after {
  background: black;
}
@keyframes pulsate {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sphere"></div>
```