# How to center and overlap DIVs

Tags: html, css

I have 2 DIVs, that I want to center and overlap. The smaller one is to lay on top of the bigger one.

It works great at full-screen, but if I decrease the browser size, the top/smaller one moves to the left.

```html
<div style="position: relative; top: 160px; border: thin solid gray; border-radius: 10px; width: 300px; height: 64px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; z-index: 1; background: url(...); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:top; background-color: #4b2f84">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 15%; width: 70%; background: white; border: thin solid gray; border-radius: 10px; height: 500px; padding: 50px 30px; margin: auto">something
</div>
```

Comment: Can the purple div be a child of the other div?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overlap two centered elements using CSS flexbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960243/overlap-two-centered-elements-using-css-flexbox), but there are actually a large number of questions on SO about centering/overlapping divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use `left: 50%;` combined with `transform: translateX(-50%);` when trying to center and overlap content.

The content is offset 50% to the left, and then -50% of its width to the left.. or `(this.left == parent.x + parent.width* 0.5 - this.width*0.5)`

```css
#div1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 160px;
  border: thin solid gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url(...);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  background-color: #4b2f84
}
#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 70%;
  background: white;
  border: thin solid gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 50px 30px;
  margin: auto
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="div2">something</div>
```